# How to add action bar to Android app?

Tags: java, android

I just start with Android. Want to add action bar following the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html). I was added `res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml`:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:NecoSeparator="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      NecoSeparator:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />

<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
```

In `MainActivity.java` i do:

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

But Eclipse says that cant find : `R.menu.main_activity_actions`.

What's wrong with this code? I have to do something more with this xml file?

**UPDATE**

```
MainActivity.java

package com.example.necoseparator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    }
```

Comment: did you import `R` correctly? clean your project and try again

Comment: I just copy code snippets from tutorial. But i can find another xml files from folder `res/menu` useing `R.menu.`.

Comment: can you post `MainActivity` please?

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+O (or Cmd+Shift+O on a Mac) to auto-fix imports.

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan : i added MainActivity.java in question.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html

Comment: import `com.example.necoseparator.R` use command of Aron and import that

Comment: @CodeLover: I seated min and max api versions as 7 and 18 yet. Or there somting else what i not do?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan: I added this import but after Ctrl+Shift+O its was removed.

Comment: put your mouse on `R` on R.menu.main_activity_actions and in quick fix import that, if use Eclipse in windows you can press Ctrl+1

Comment: Ctrl+1 returt `No suggestions avaible` for R.

Comment: In R.jsva i can't find nothing about `main_activity_actions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think main problem is to saving your menu layout, if you have an error in file its might happened. please change your menu file with my code and save that and import R file (make sure that is not `android.R` and its must be `YourPackageName.R`) then clean your project and run.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="filtered"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_load"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_luncher"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="update"/>

 </menu>
```

Comment: see new Edit @KliverMax

Comment: I start application about 10 times, and lastly `main_activity_actions` appeared in R.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line `xmlns:NecoSeparator="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` and try again

```
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Toolbar

toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

and add list of menus